# Spring Integration : Message is getting redelivered to queue on JMS transaction rollback

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a  Spring Integration application (Spring Version 4.3.1.RELEASE) which has a listener for consuming JMS Messages off an Solace (version 7.0.0.63) Queue.

I want the messages to be consumed in a JMS transaction. If there is an exception during message consumption, I expect transaction to be rolled back and message to be rolled back. As per the logs I see that message is being read from the queue and processed till the end of my Spring Integration flow but I see JMS transactions is rolled back after the processing. This issue is only for some of the messages and some messages are getting processed successfully without any issue. Below is the JMS listener configuration and error message seen in the logs.

JMS Listener Configuration:

```
    <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
    id="appMessageDrivenChannelAdapter"
    send-timeout="5000"
    max-messages-per-task="-1"
    idle-task-execution-limit="100"
    max-concurrent-consumers="1"
    connection-factory="appCachedConnectionFactory"
    destination="appInQueue" 
    channel="appChannel" 
    error-channel="defaultErrorChannel"
    acknowledge="transacted"/>

  <bean id="appCachedConnectionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="appConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="cacheConsumers" value="false" />
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" />
</bean> 

  <bean id="appConnectionFactory" 
  class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" >
    <property name="jndiTemplate">
        <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
    </property>
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>jndiName</value>
    </property>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Error Message in Logs:

```
 Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.</L_MSG>
javax.jms.TransactionRolledBackException: Error comitting - transaction rolled back (Transaction '5238' unexpectedly rolled back during commit attempt. (((Client name:   Local addr:    Remote addr: ) - )  com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPErrorResponseException: 503: Message Consume Failure [Subcode:48]))
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1531.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.solacesystems.jms.impl.JMSExceptionValue.newInstance(JMSExceptionValue.java:32) ~[jms-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jms.impl.JCSMPExceptionMapper$ArrayListMapper.get(JCSMPExceptionMapper.java:31) ~[jms-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jms.impl.JCSMPExceptionMapper.get(JCSMPExceptionMapper.java:90) ~[jms-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jms.impl.Validator.createJMSException(Validator.java:541) ~[jms-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jms.SolSession.commit(SolSession.java:178) ~[jms-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2985.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:386) ~[spring-jms-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1010.commit(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.commitIfNecessary(JmsUtils.java:217) ~[spring-jms-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.commitIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:761) [spring-jms-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:665) [spring-jms-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:319) [spring-jms-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257) [spring-jms-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1166) [spring-jms-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158) [spring-jms-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055) [spring-jms-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_92] 

Caused by: com.solacesystems.jcsmp.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction '5238' unexpectedly rolled back during commit attempt. (((Client name:   Local addr:    Remote addr: ) - )  com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPErrorResponseException: 503: Message Consume Failure [Subcode:48])
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.transaction.TSState$StateCommitting.handleAsyncAdCtrl(TSState.java:528) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.transaction.TransactedSessionImpl.handleControlMessage(TransactedSessionImpl.java:326) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.transaction.TransactedSessionManager.dispatchAssuredCtrlMessage(TransactedSessionManager.java:91) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.transaction.TransactedSessionManagerSmf.handleAsyncAssuredCtrlMessage(TransactedSessionManagerSmf.java:167) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.transaction.TransactedSessionManager.handleAsyncAssuredCtrlMessage(TransactedSessionManager.java:79) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel.handleAssuredCtrlMsg(TcpClientChannel.java:1544) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel.handleMessage(TcpClientChannel.java:1498) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.nio.impl.SubscriberMessageReader.processRead(SubscriberMessageReader.java:97) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.nio.impl.SubscriberMessageReader.read(SubscriberMessageReader.java:132) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.smf.SimpleSmfClient.read(SimpleSmfClient.java:1127) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.nio.impl.SyncEventDispatcherReactor.processReactorChannels(SyncEventDispatcherReactor.java:206) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.nio.impl.SyncEventDispatcherReactor.eventLoop(SyncEventDispatcherReactor.java:157) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.nio.impl.SyncEventDispatcherReactor$SEDReactorThread.run(SyncEventDispatcherReactor.java:338) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
... 1 more


Caused by: com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPErrorResponseException: 503: Message Consume Failure
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.transaction.TransactedSessionManagerSmf.handleAsyncAssuredCtrlMessage(TransactedSessionManagerSmf.java:153) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.transaction.TransactedSessionManager.handleAsyncAssuredCtrlMessage(TransactedSessionManager.java:79) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel.handleAssuredCtrlMsg(TcpClientChannel.java:1544) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel.handleMessage(TcpClientChannel.java:1498) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.nio.impl.SubscriberMessageReader.processRead(SubscriberMessageReader.java:97) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.nio.impl.SubscriberMessageReader.read(SubscriberMessageReader.java:132) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.smf.SimpleSmfClient.read(SimpleSmfClient.java:1127) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.nio.impl.SyncEventDispatcherReactor.processReactorChannels(SyncEventDispatcherReactor.java:206) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.nio.impl.SyncEventDispatcherReactor.eventLoop(SyncEventDispatcherReactor.java:157) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.nio.impl.SyncEventDispatcherReactor$SEDReactorThread.run(SyncEventDispatcherReactor.java:338) ~[jcsmp-7.0.0.63.jar:?]
...
```

Comment: This is badly formatted question. Sorry, nobody is going to help you here if you are not going to respect our time for reading about your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ArtemBilan: Sorry for the trouble. I was trying to edit the question but was not able to do it. I had added the JMS Listener Configuration

Comment: I've edited your question for better readability.

Comment: Maybe you have more stack trace? With the `Caused by`. Not clear by current log what is the reason on that rollback. What is the question though?

Comment: Hi Artem,I had added stacktrace. The problem I am facing is the message getting rolled back to queue even after successful processing. Thus the messages are getting processed multiple times. I am not sure of the root cause of the issue that is resulting in rollback of the messages as this is happening for only some messages. Some messages get processed fine.

Comment: OK. You may consider to use `<idempotent-receiver>` to filter out messages you have processed before: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#idempotent-receiver

Comment: But that definitely would be great to drill out the cause of the rollback. Maybe something like `DEBUG` for the root category may help you to determine what's going on?

Comment: idempotent-receiver is already being used. But there is a db transaction in the flow which also is facing a rollback due to this error.

Comment: @ArtemBilan: In the logs I see a warning Message Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set. The listener has an error channel defined  error-channel="defaultErrorChannel" which is creating an entry into database. But I do not see any entry in the database. Could you please let me know how can I set up a error Handler for the listener.                                                                                                  I will also enable debug level  logs and try to drill down on the root cause of this issue.

Comment: The `error-channel` and `errorHandler` work on different levels. There is a `container` attribute on the `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` and already on that `AbstractMessageListenerContainer` bean you can configure an `errorHandler`